# How to use theme from github.io site for Github Project Pages sites

Tags: jekyll, navbar, travis-ci, github-pages

I've been working on [my website](https://pavelkomarov.com) on and off for a couple years, learned a ton about JavaScript, CSS, HTML, Bootstrap, Jekyll, Travis-CI, and Github Pages in the process. (Long list is a major factor in why it's taken so long.)

I've discovered that if I push to (or have Travis deploy to) the `gh-pages` branch of a repo, it actually becomes a subdomain of my website. Examples: [here](https://pavelkomarov.com/exportify), [here](https://pavelkomarov.com/bloom-filter), [here](https://pavelkomarov.com/big-holes-in-big-data).

This is pretty awesome, but those sub-pages end up feeling like they're not a part of the same website, because they provide no way to get back to the main page. I'd like them to include my navbar.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: I'd also like my favicon to be present on the subdomains. I could obviously go around adding it and the navbar to every readme, but that's inelegant. I'd rather point travis at the existing code and somehow get it to dynamically add that stuff before publishing.

Comment: This is the little corner of hate toward Jekyll I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yesterday I finally went through and did [what I theorized about in September](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57909413/2084503). [The result lives here now](https://github.com/pavelkomarov/hyde). This was not an easy process, [despite the documentation trying to be helpful](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/), because the intersection of Jekyll and GitHub pages is such a massively complicated opaque box, and ruby was unfamiliar to me. But ultimately it boils down to a few important steps and gotchas:

1. You're gonna need ruby and several packages. `sudo apt install ruby` should give you `ruby` (interpreter) and `gem` (package manager).

   - Gotcha 1a: The basics are left unexplained, so allow me: Ruby code comes in packages called gems, which are a lot like python packages. They're managed by `gem` or `bundler` rather than `pip` and hosted on `rubygems.org` instead of `pypi`. Much like in the Python world where everyone sings the praises of `conda`, everyone in the Ruby world sings the praises of `bundler`, which is itself a gem, one that you have to `gem install` because it doesn't come packaged with ruby like `gem` itself. I found bundler to be buggy; it hung when I tried to `bundle install github-pages` (more on `github-pages` later). Also, bundler relies on yet more configuration files called `Gemfile`s, which are the analog of the `requirements.txt` files `pip` *can* but doesn't *need* to ingest. Honestly who wants more of that clutter lying around for a small project with no complicated dependency tree? And who wants to have to `bundle exec jekyll serve` instead of just `jekyll serve`? Are you kidding me? Just use `gem` to install things, and skip the `Gemfile`. Much like `pip`, I find simpler is better.
   - Gotcha 1b: If you `sudo apt install jekyll`, you get an old version, like 3.1 or something. But Jekyll is a gem; you can and should install using the package manager. (But actually don't do this, because it comes as part of the `github-pages` gem, and the versions don't agree. More on that later.)
   - Gotcha 1c: Oh, what's that? You want to `gem install jekyll` (or even `gem install bundler`)? Yeah, sorry, I can't do that because there's some stuff missing, and here's a long printout about it. *...Google, Google...* `sudo apt install ruby-dev`. Oh, sorry I *still* can't build. Here are some *other* errors. *...Google, Google...* `sudo apt install g++`. Okay *now* it works. This process might be slightly different for you; point is setting up a ruby environment can be dicey.
   - Gotcha 1d: Oh what's that? Now you want to be able to call `jekyll` from the command line like you could if you just installed it with `apt`? Well, sorry, I'm `gem`, and some times I don't put `jekyll` on your path. If this happens to you, pay attention to where `gem` saves the gems, go find the executable within, and then create a symlink with `sudo ln -s /path/to/jekyll /usr/bin/jekyll`
2. Move `assets`, `_includes`, `_layouts`, and `_sass` from the site to a new repo. Done. Bam. You have a remote theme now. It really should be that easy, but...

   - Gotcha 2a: No one tells you that's the minimum viable product, so you have to start by understanding what remote themes are and how they work. According to canon, they're full-blown gems. When you reference one, Jekyll needs to go and fetch it before it can generate your site. [The Jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/#publishing-your-theme) is all about coaching you on how to truly package up your theme as a gem and push it up to `rubygems.org`, which requires: (1) a rubygems account, (2) for your theme to contain an abstruse `.gemspec` file, the contents of which are not well explained. Keep reading for why this is irrelevant.
   - Gotcha 2b: You have to understand how *GitHub Pages* actually uses remote themes. On this topic GitHub is happy to tell you about adding `remote_theme: user/theme-name` to the leveraging site's `_config.yml` (Jekyll config), but they neglect to tell you upfront whether they're pulling in a gem from somewhere or what. Turns out they're using yet another gem called [`jekyll-remote-theme`](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme) to pull the raw files directly from a repo, making the step of compiling and uploading a gem and having a `.gemspec` no one understands or wants to look at unnecessary. (Hooray.) benbalter's documentation for the remote theme gem itself is the only place I could find this information.
   - Gotcha 2c: Beware that because [Pages is still on Jekyll 3.8.6](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/issues/422#issuecomment-567089139), you don't have certain functionality on GitHub Pages that you might want, [like being able to define site data in the theme's `_config.yml`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/7971). As a result, my front-matter-prepended `.css` containing a few Liquid tags that worked just fine as part of my unseparated site ended up with emptystring tag substitutions in the generated site. I ended up [hard-coding some variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59719859/2084503) in the theme.
   - Gotcha 2d: Any other folders and files--not among `assets`, `_includes`, `_layouts`, and `_sass`--(I had one named `theme` containing stuff like my favicon.) don't get folded in to a theme gem or transported via the `jekyll-remote-theme` mechanism employed by GitHub. By carefully amending the `.gemspec`, you can include those files in a gem, but this method has no effect on the behavior of `jekyll-remote-theme`, so I ended up basically putting everything in `assets`.
   - Complaint 2e: [Ruby Sass is apparently deprecated now?](https://sass-lang.com/blog/ruby-sass-is-deprecated) Why has Jekyll continued to use it for so long? I've still not encountered an example where it seems useful.
3. Put a `_config.yml` containing `remote_theme: yourname/yourtheme` in the root directory of the `gh-pages` branch of every repo for which you want the Project Pages rendered in your theme. No Gemfile, no nonsense. Just wait for it to deploy.

   - Gotcha 3a: Jekyll looks *specifically* for a `page.html` file inside `_layouts` to render `readme` contents. If you have a `page.html`, then you can add your head, navbar and other `_includes` stuff to it with Liquid tags no problem. If you happened to forget this file or think Jekyll could use `post.html` instead, well then you'd be wrong, and the theme isn't applied. Not sure whether `default.html` would work as a failover. In any case, GitHub pages with Jekyll is *super* brittle, and I'm honestly lucky to have discovered this without being blocked by it, because (1) I haven't seen any GitHub documentation to describe exactly which commands are being called to generate Project Pages, (2) you can't see the terminal output for the remote compilation process**, and (3), because you don't know what GitHub is doing, there is no way to replicate it locally to see warnings or error printouts--that is *if* Jekyll even warns you about this.
     **If there actually is a way to view this somewhere, please tell me. [GitHub says](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites): "When you push changes to your publishing source on GitHub, GitHub Pages will attempt to build your site. If the build fails, you'll receive an email at your primary email address. You'll also receive emails for build warnings. You can see build failures (but not build warnings) for your site on GitHub in the Settings tab of your site's repository." I did receive an email stating "The tag `include_cached` on line 15 in `/_layouts/default.html` is not a recognized Liquid tag.", but I don't remember which build this was for, and I can't find the failure recorded in the repo Settings anywhere.
   - Gotcha 3b: If you update the theme, Pages sites which use the theme aren't rebuilt to reflect the theme changes. You have to manually repush to the branch a site is built from to trigger a site rebuild. This is pretty easy for repos I've integrated with Travis-CI, because I can just go down the list rerunning the most recent builds, which culminate in pushes to `gh-pages` branches, which in turn cause Pages servers to rebuild. But for other sites, I have to either make some legitimate change or push an empty commit.
4. Add `plugins: - jekyll-remote-theme` and `remote_theme: yourname/yourtheme` to the `_config.yml` in your User Pages site.

   - Gotcha 4a: Local execution is confusing. [benbalter's readme](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme) is pretty good, but the Usage section still assumes you're using `bundler`. If you're not, then `gem install github-pages` like you'd install any other gem. This gem is really a huge list of other gems Pages servers actually run to generate your static site, including the same versions of `jekyll` and `jekyll-remote-theme`. You'll want these so you can catch all subtle version or display bugs locally and have no surprises in the cloud. Finally, despite it not seeming to be necessary for actual deployment, for local execution you have to make sure to list `jekyll-remote-theme` as a plugin in your leveraging site's `_config.yml`. Otherwise `jekyll serve` errors.
   - Gotcha 4b: Local execution with a remote theme is broken--or [at least it is for Jekyll 4.0.0](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme/issues/66). It works fine for Jekyll 3, which is what GitHub Pages servers use, which is why it deploys fine. If you get Jekyll with `gem install jekyll` rather than from the `github-pages` list, you might get errors as I did.

So basically it's not hard in hindsight, but getting there is a frustrating fiasco of flying blind with only overly verbose, disappointingly incomplete maps to guide you. I wish GitHub would show you the whole process of site compilation and deployment in some terminal, like Travis-CI does for builds. And I wish Jekyll weren't so complicated. There are too many features, and too many things fail silently.

I hope this research can help somebody else.

Comment: As of today, github pages still uses ruby 2.7 and jekyll 3.9 https://pages.github.com/versions/. Why? ruby 3 and jekyll 4 have been out for _years!_

Comment: It's worth noting that site compilation and deployment no longer happens in the dark, now that we have github actions. 

Answer (score 2):

I haven't implemented this yet, so more to come as I do, but I think I've found the canonical solution and want to document it for myself.

All Github Pages sites have a theme. You can either:

1. Go to Settings -> Options -> scroll down to Github Pages and [select a theme from the theme chooser](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-jekyll-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-with-the-jekyll-theme-chooser). This is *lame*, because there are only a few default choices, and you don't get to customize the theme yourself to reflect the idiosyncrasies of your site. Nor do off-the-shelf themes allow you to use the navbar from another site.
2. Or you can add a `_config.yml` file to your project that github will try to read and follow when it generates your Github Pages site. Therein you can specify a `theme`, one of several whitelisted choices (a limited list), or a [`remote_theme`](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-jekyll-theme-to-your-github-pages-site), which can be created by anyone. This is *great*, because you can specify your own theme.

This means the way to have consistent navbar and theme and everything across the [User Pages Site and all my Project Pages Sites](https://help.github.com/en/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages) is to tease out my theme from the User Pages Site into its own repo and then reference it from all those other sites in config files.

Sounds like a chore, but it helps improve reuseability for sure.

I may also need to specify `index.md` in the top level of each project, to supplant the readme as the homepage and ensure content like `<head>` stuff and navbar make it in.